# is it possible to style the overflow of a div to have a lower opacity

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a twitter-like image cropper. I have an image loaded into a div that handles the cropping itself i just wonder is there a way i can show the overflow of the div at a lower opacity then what is inside the div?
I cant find any styling rules that could accomplish this.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px;" class="jwc_frame">
<img src="data:image/" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 300px;" class="jwc_image" id="preview"><div class="jwc_loader">Upload Image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a fiddle please

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do such trickery. See the approach of imgAreaSelect - basically it's drawing at least 4 divs around the selection. Visit http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://codepen.io/janhommes/pen/eaKsA). It uses a div for every direction.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this trick: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8r3o8bdp/1/)**

inside a container I've just put 2 div with same image. One with the "crop" and the other with full image and the opacity (at half), then make the opacity image to have overflow visible and place the crop one over the other with position absolute.

```
.image {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:visible;
    opacity:0.5;

}
.image-top {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is admittedly pretty 'hacky', but it works and doesn't require extra divs everywhere. Just set a huge shadow on the element, and set overflow hidden on the container.

```
box-shadow:0 0 0 500px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
```

fiddle-> http://jsfiddle.net/z8d5n287/

Comment: This a a nice work around. Pity the image itself (out of the box) won't have any trasparency as Op asked. But never though of using box-shadow that way.